# spring servlet xml vs application context xml

Tags: spring-mvc

In spring mvc, I have read that if you have a servlet called MyAction then the correspondign config file should be called MyAction-servlet.xml. But then some sources say that the spring config file should be called applicationContext.xml.
Which one is used when?

Comment: You don't need both BTW for a basic web app. You can just use x-servlet.xml . applicationContext.xml IS a parent context config though, meaning you can refer to beans in it from other context configs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually 2 separate contexts that get created in a web application that uses spring:

1. The first context is that of the application itself. By default this reads from **applicationContext.xml**. You can override this by using the **contextConfigLocation** context parameters.
2. The second context is that of dispatcher servlet. By default, this reads from the file **(your-dispatcher-servlet-name)-servlet.xml** unless you override it by using the init-param **contextConfigLocation** as well.

I hope this explains.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate a bit more on why we need 2 contexts? Also...the ContextLoaderListerner will listen on which context being loaded?